# Ayuda: estructurar sitio con Vue js, Server web y Server API

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

como estan? Queria consultar si hay alguna manera que se estile, ya sea en performance o directamente como buenas practicas, para lo siguiente:
La aplicacion del lado web es con Vue js, tambien existira una API para que sea consumida tanto por web y aplicaciones mobile. Del lado del Server uso Laravel.

Entonces, lo que quiero es consumir la API siempre desde el cliente web, pero antes deberia loguearme. Si me logueo via web, luego necesitaria que el server me devuelva el index, el cual contendra las compilaciones completas para trabajar con Vue, pero cuando quiera comenzar a consumir la API, me estaria faltando el token (como si me hubiera logueado via API con passport o cualquier otro). El Server API podria estar en otro server distinto al web.
Consultas:
.- Es correcto loguearme el el Server web, y que este se loguee en el server API? Entonces seguirira trabajando contra el web, y que este usara proxys para comunicarse con la API. O sea, la parte web actuarian como pasamano unicamente.

.- La otra, es que me loguee contra el web, que este se loguee contra el API y logre devolver ese token al cliente web, y ahi comenzar solamente a interactuar con la API. Con esto, dejarian el Server web un poco obsoleto, ya que lo estaria usando solo para loguearme y me de todos los archivos Vue, ya ya.

.- El ultimo, es partir desde el formulario de login (que el usuario lo deberia obtenerlo de alguna forma), luego loguearse, y luego obtener las compilaciones Vue para continuar consumiendo la API. Lo que no me queda claro, y me refiero a mejores practicas para no desperdiciar recursos, es, en este escenario, como obtendria al form de Login, y mas importante, una vez logueado contra la API, obtener el site completo en Vue, puesto que la API no deberia entregarte este tipo de informacion, es correcto?
Perdon si fue extensa la consulta. Espero que se haya entendido lo que quiero hacer.

La consulta va mas orientada a cual es la mejor practica o lo que se estila en estos casos.
Gracias !!
Saludos !

G.

Comment: saludos y bienvenido, te recomiendo leer [ask] pues tu publicación aunque interesante se sale de los lineamientos del sitio al ser muy amplia y basada en opiniones; toda vez que te hago estas recomendaciones para evitar te cierren la pregunta; del mismo modo por favor haz el [tour]

Comment: En serio?? No doy detalles que no vengan al caso, estoy omitiendo otras cosas de infraestructura para no escibir de mas, y previo a la pregunta tengo que dar a conocer el contexto para que las respuestas, si las hay, no sean confusas......
Hay alguna seccion en especial para estas discusiones? Porque es un problema que necesito resolver.....no es un intrcambio de opiniones....aunque lo creas asi.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy en un proyecto casi identico. Yo pensaria que el login debe ser parte de la app de Vue y solo pasar a otros componentes (con las funcionalidades de ruteo de Vue) si se ha superado la autenticacion. Con esto logras que se sirvan todos los archivos de tu app de una sola vez, y no tener que hacer varias peticiones al servidor para la misma app, que en mi opinion, no va muy bien con la filosofia de las Single Page Aplication.

Cuando se sirva la app, ya puede venir incluido el token desde el servidor y no tendrias ningun problema en usarlo para la autenticacion y tenerlo disponible despues cuando sea necesario.

Si se hace de esta manera, puedes deshacerte de un servidor intermedio y solo consultar la API con Vue y manejar toda la logica con Javascript, incluso guardar el token en cache o en cookies para otras funcionalidades.